# How do I pass type as a parameter of function in go?

Tags: go

so I have a struct

```golang
type Book struct {
    Name   string
    Author string
}
```

and here is the code when i use this struct

```golang
func Add(obj string) {
    res, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}

func main() {
    Open("./example.json")
    book := Book{"test", "me"}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(book).String())
    Add(book)
}
```

Now what i wanna do is pass that book object or variable in the function `Add` and when I try to do this it gives me an error.

```
cannot use book (type Book) as type string in argument to Add
```

So How do I solve it and how do i pass `book` object as a parameter in the function `Add`?

Comment: Just use `func Add(obj Book)`, or what am I missing... ?

Comment: `Add()` expects a value of type `string`. `Book` is a different type, you can't pass `book` to it, only a `string`. If `Add()` needs a `Book`, declare it to expect a book: `func Add(obj Book)`.

Comment: Do you want to encode it as json? Then try this: `func Add(obj interface{}) { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct `Book` now acts like a data type of its own. If you want to accept only this kind of data type in your `Add` function, you need to replace `string` with `Book`.

So the code would look something like this:

```golang
package main

import "encoding/json"

type Book struct {
    Name   string
    Author string
}

func Add(obj Book) {
    res, err := json.Marshal(obj)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(res))
}

func main() {
    Open("./example.json")
    book := Book{"test", "me"}
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(book).String())
    Add(book)
}
```

Comment: I passed func Add(obj interface{}), it worked

Comment: @Inferus Could you please accept an answer, so the question does not remain as open? Thank you.